# Synchronizing between UDP and TCP

Tags: c, linux, tcp, udp

I'm currently implementing a daemon server that acts as 2 servers. One of the servers is recieving logs via UDP from a collection of producers. The second server is broadcasting every log that was received from a producer to a consumer who is currently connected via TCP.

These are 2 separte sockets. My current(pretty basic) implementation is to use `select()` on these 2 sockets, and handle every read signal accordingly, so my code is basicly(NOTE this is pseudo code)

```
for(;;) {
    FDSET(consumers_server)
    FDSET(producers_server)
    select()
    if consumers_server is set:
       add new client to the consumers array
    if producers server is set:
       broadcast the log to every consumer in the array
}
```

This works just fine, the problem ocurres when this code is put in to stress. When multiple produers are sending logs(UDP) the real bottleneck here is the consumers which are TCP. Sending a log to the consumers can result in blocking, which i can't afford.

I've tried using non-blocking sockets and `select()ing` the consumers write fds, the problem is this would result in saving the non-sent logs in a buffer, until they can be sent. This results in a very unelegant massive code, and the system is also low on resources(mainly RAM)

I'm running on a linux distro.

An alternative approach to synchronize between these UDP and TCP connections would be welcomed.

Comment: Have you looked into multi-threading?

Comment: Any reason you don't use the same TCP connection for both? That setup looks like a problem for firewalls and maintenance problem. Define a proper protocol **first**, then write the code.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, the reason is that a producer cannot block and has to be very quick when sending a message. I need to distinguish between a consumer and a producer. I can't use the same socket for 2 different purposes.

Comment: XY problem. You use the wrong approach. It will not be faster just because you use more sockets.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the readers can't keep up?

Answer (score 1):

This is doomed to failure. Sooner or later you will be unable to send to the TCP consumer. Whether that manifests itself as blocking or EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK isn't really relevant to the underlying problem, which is that the producer is overrunning the consumer. You have to decide what to do about that. You can have a certain amount of internal buffering but at some point you will have to stop reading from the UDP producers. At that point, UDP datagrams will be dropped and your system will lose data, and of course it is liable to lose data anyway by virtue of using UDP.

Don't do this. Use TCP for the producers: or else just accept the data loss and use blocking mode. Non-blocking mode only moves the problem slightly and complicates your code.